# Find minimum Characters required from the subtreee

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, tree

You are given a rooted tree with N nodes. Each node contains a lowercase English letter. Node with label 1 is the root.
There are Q questions of the form,
X S: Here X is the root of subtree and S is a string.

For each question, let T be the string built using all the characters in the nodes of subtree with root X (each subtree node character comes exactly once) .
For each question, print minimum number of characters to be added to T , so that the we can build S using some characters of string T 
(each character of string T can be used at most once).

Input Format:

The first line of input consists of two space separated integers 
N and Q that are number of nodes in the tree and number of questions respectively.
Next line will contain 
N space separated lowercase English letters, where ith letter will be the letter stored in node with label i .
Each of the next N−1 lines contains two space separated integers 
u and v that denote there is an edge between nodes with labels u and v
Next Q lines follow. Each line will contain an integer 
X that denotes the node label and a string 
S separated by a single space.

Output Format:

For each query, print the required answer in a new line.

Input Constraints
2≤N≤105
1≤Q≤105
1≤u,v≤N;u!=v
1≤X≤N

All characters in nodes and string are lowercase English letters.
Sum of lengths of strings in all the questions is at most 10^6

Sample Input

8 3

o v s l v p d i

1 3

8 3

4 8

6 1

5 3

7 6

2 3

7 ifwrxl

4 eyljywnm

3 llvse

Sample Output:

6

7

2

Explanation

Query 1- Character in the subtree with root 7 is d, we need 6 
characters(i,f,w,r,x,l) to make S=(ifwrxl).

Query 2- Character in the subtree with root 4 is l, we need 7 characters(e,y,j,y,w,n,m) to make S=(eyljywnm).

Query 3- Characters in the subtree with root 3 are (v,s,i,l), we need 2 characters(l,e) to make S=(llvse).

Comment: I have an vague idea on how to solve this problem using multi list. But I couldn't proceed further with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Multilevel Linklist with **head, down pointer, left pointer** to maintain the node level. And iterate the node given by query into multilevel Linklist then compare Query string with down pointer nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the quires are very high `(10^5 )`, Iterating over sub-tree and checking with given string's frequency will not be an efficient one. You can easily solve this kind of problem using `MO's algorithm in tree`.So that each query can be solved in `Sqrt(N)` complexity, resulting overall `O(Q*Sqrt(N))` complexity.
You may look at [this](https://blog.anudeep2011.com/mos-algorithm/) for more details about MO's algorithm.

> Note: I could provide implementation details if needed.

Comment: Could you please provide the implementation details

Comment: @irs102info, If there exist link to problem details page in some online judge, it would be better. Is there any link?